# How to make Wordpress Contact Form 7 Shortcode vary depending on page GET value?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Wordpress with Template form 7.

I've got pages 1,2,3 with links to the feedback page feedback:

1. site.com/page1/ with URL = a href = "site.com/feedback?type=1"
2. site.com/page2/ with URL = a href = "site.com/feedback?type=2"
3. site.com/page3/ with URL = a href = "site.com/feedback?type=3"

I want to show special layout of Contact Form 7 depend on variable value (type 1, type 2, type 3)

This plugin Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension ([link here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/#description)) can read var value, But I can't switch special Contact Form 7 block according to var value. :-(

I found this plugin - [Contact Form 7 - Conditional Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) (but it create fields for one forms). But I need to show on page 3 "ready to insert" templates:-(

is it possible to show Contact Form 7 id shortcode depend on site.com/feedback?type=(number)?

Thanks in advance for advices.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom shortcode to call contact form 7 that uses the `$_GET` parameter from the URL.  You'll have to place this function in your functions.php of your child theme or theme.  Replace the contact-form-7 id's with the ones you're using.  Also... you can keep going and put as many as you want.  You could also use a php `switch` instead of if elseif, etc.

So on your page template, don't use the `[contact-form-7]` shortcode, instead just put `[my-cf7]`

```
add_shortcode('my-cf7', 'so_61464677_cf7_shortcode');
function so_61464677_cf7_shortcode(){
    if ($_GET['type'] == 2){
        return do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2"]');
    } elseif ($_GET['type'] == 3) {
        return do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="3"]');
    } else {
        return do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1"]');
    }
}
```